# How To Change Caption Background Color in Fusion Slider?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-color, caption

I am using Avada Theme on my WordPress website. Although the theme provides enough flexibility to modify anything using settings, however, there is some problem with the caption background color on slides in fusion slider.

I have created a slider using fusion slider and have created three different slides for that slider all with different text and background images. I am also open to modifying each and everything on slides using settings. However, I am unable to modify the caption background color on each slide. When I place an RGBA value like `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)` or a hexadecimal code like `#4DFFFFFF`, I always get `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);` result on the front end.

The setting does not provide any other feature which can help me force the functionality in order to replace the caption background color with whatever I need.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

NOTE: I do not want to use any CSS code in my style.css. I just need this to be done with setting.

Comment: *"I do not want to use any CSS code in my style.css. I just need this to be done with setting."* - Then this is not a programming question.

Comment: @mumpitz If I had to use CSS code, then why will I post here? I clearly mention the scenario that I do not need any CSS code. Because my client can edit settings, not CSS code.